# Counting common values in two arrays

Tags: time-complexity, arrays

> given two arrays of integers A and B of size m, with values in the
>   range [-n,n]. I want an algorithm to count how many common values are
>   in A and B , if a value is repeated we only count it once , for
>   example :  $A=\{2,2,14,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,14,14,5\}$ the algorithm
>   should return 2 . Problem is I need to do this in $O(m)$ time.

My attempt was to create an array $C$, of size $2n$.
and increment all the values of $A$ and $B$ by $n$, and count the values of $A$ like: 
$C[A[i]] = 1$
that would take me $O(m)$ time , and $O(1)$ time to create the array. 
then going over $B$ and counting how many $1's$ I encounter in $C$.

So far it sounds good, however I have no idea what's in $C$ in the first place and it could be that there's a $1$ in there already and that would increment the counter falsely , and initializing $C$ would take $O(n)$ time.

Any ideas?
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following algorithm:

1. For $1 \leq i \leq m$: $C[A[i]] = 0$
2. For $1 \leq i \leq m$: $C[B[i]] = 1$
3. Initialize *answer* to $0$
4. For $1 \leq i \leq m$:

   - If $C[A[i]] = 1$ then $C[A[i]] = 2$ and increment *answer*
5. Return *answer*

Comment: Could you further explain what 4 means? And could it be that 1 will overwrite 0 in C if there is a value in both A and B?

Comment: Perhaps you should try in on some example and see what happens. Plus, there’s always the possibility I made some mistake.

Comment: Well I don’t understand what you mean by if $C[A[i]] = 1: C[A[i]] = 2$ , increment answer what’s the condition and what is the consequent?

Comment: Hope it’s clearer now.

Comment: Impressive ( from my perspective) . Thanks a lot!